# selenium python need to press option key on mac os

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
body = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.OPTION + 'f')
```

output:

```
    body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.OPTION + 'f')
AttributeError: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'OPTION'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It somehow makes no sense for me: what if you visit that webpage from a linux or windows machine? What keys would you press then? .. Seriously, what am I missing here?

Comment: in this case, I need to write code specifically for mac os, in case of switching to windows or linux, I will simply change the sending of keys in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply use `Keys.COMMAND` instead of `Keys.CONTROL` for MacOS, for one thing.

Unfortunately there is no built-in "OPTION" in the [Selenium Keys class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys), but I would try using this code instead: `"\u2325"`.

Finally, I am not sure if you can perform this simply with `element.send_keys()`. Maybe you can. But I would probably use `ActionChains`, something like this:

```
# need this import
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).key_down("\u2325").send_keys('f').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).key_up("\u2353").perform()
```

Could be more readable like this:

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click(on_element = body) # put focus on desired element
action.key_down(Keys.COMMAND)
action.key_down("\u2325")
action.send_keys('f')
action.key_up(Keys.COMMAND)
action.key_up("\u2325")
action.perform()
action.reset_actions() # Clears actions that are already stored locally and on the remote end
```

Comment: thanks, but about the control key, it is also on mac os, how can I press it?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. What exactly are you trying to do here? On my mac, control+option+f does nothing.

Comment: this keyboard shortcut opens the menu I need in a google document

Comment: OK, so you want to open the "File" dropdown. Why don't you just click it? `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#docs-file-menu').click()`

Comment: I just need to open "page setup" after that and earlier in some tests it just didn't open for some reason, after that I found a solution in the form of control + option + f + g

Comment: and since I couldn’t reproduce this keyboard shortcut on my own, I asked a question here ..

Comment: Well, just as code `"\u2325"` indications "option", I found that `"\u2303"` is such for the control button. Maybe that could work?

Comment: I didn’t really understand why, but instead of pressing a hot key, these characters were entered into the text of the file: ⌃⌥fg

Comment: This is getting more complicated. The only way I can think to actually solve it then, would be to add that unicode and the additional keys you need to the `Keys` class in the Selenium source code itself. Which is not actually that bad, but not ideal to depart from Selenium's trunk. I think I will make a ticket with Selenium to implement these keys, and perhaps fix it myself.

Comment: @SneakIhelp see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10912

Comment: thx, I'll think about this keyboard shortcut, maybe something will work out :)